# SQL Server stored procedure solution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns two columns `Start` and `end dates`. What will be stored procedure to convert into distinct dates list which include all of the dates in between as well.

Examples of Events:

```
      StartDate          EndDate    
•   1/2/2012 6:00   -   1/2/2012 9:00 
•   1/2/2012 11:00  -   1/2/2012 19:00  
•   1/1/2012 11:00  -   1/5/2012 19:00  
•   1/7/2012 11:00  -   1/8/2012 19:00  
•   1/11/2012 11:00 -   1/11/2012 19:00
```

Result:

```
    •   1/1/2012 
    •   1/2/2012 
    •   1/3/2012 
    •   1/4/2012 
    •   1/5/2012 
    •   1/7/2012 
    •   1/8/2012 
    •   1/11/2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,StartDate),0) as StartDate from table
union
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,EndDate),0) from table
```